# Check if array has element with specific length

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to get element with specific length (ex: length = 7) in array
If there's no element with length = 7, I want to print something.
If I do inside the loop it will print many times base on number of element.

```
let txt = `abc klj 1123 MPM SN67990 MKP LJJ`
let arr = txt.split(' ')
console.log(arr)

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

    if (arr[i].length == 7) {
        console.log(arr[i])
    } 
    
    // TODO: if no element with length = 7 in arr
}
```

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+check+if+array+has+no+element+satisfies+condition) of [Check if all elements satisfy a condition with for-loop](/q/49653831/4642212).

Comment: So add a variable and check outside `var hasItem = false; for(...) { if(length 7) { hasItem=true;}} if(!hasItem) { alert('nope'); }`

Answer (score 2):

Check that `.every` one of the elements passes the length test.

```
if (arr.every(subarr => subarr.length !== 7)) {
  // then no array with length 7 exists
}
```

Another method - use a regular expression to match 7 characters, no array required.

```
if (!txt.match(/\b\S{7}\b/)) {
  // then no word exactly 7 characters long exists
}
```